Pandas apply is turning matrices into nan/None
I am running the following code on a dataset trying to tally the rows from one data set that match a varied set of criteria. I am using the apply function to store this tally inside of a matrix, where I call a secondary function which serves only to change a single value of the matrix. For reasons not at all obvious to me, this matrix column sometimes turns into type float with nan, or in other iterations of the code turns into type NoneType, leading to the error "type ___ not indexable" (in this case the first 91 runs of this loop are successful, the 92nd run causes error.)
I am reproducing the entire relevant code sections because I cannot figure out where this error arises from.
function causing error:
#######################################
# takes in year and month ex: ("12", "01")
# loads creates time series data with matrix of shared rides
#######################################
def processMonth(year, month):
    print("Processing " + year + "-" + month)
    
    #read in correct month data
    currentMonth = pd.read_parquet("blocked/20" + year + "/data_wBlocks_20" + year + "-" + month + ".parquet")

    #Cleaning Data:
    #remove whitespace from columns
    currentMonth.columns = currentMonth.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
    #drop rows with no match in either side
    currentMonth.dropna(inplace=True)
    #convert datetime to date
    currentMonth["pickup_datetime"] = currentMonth["pickup_datetime"].dt.date
    
    #create new df as time series on business days for daily ride vols
    MonthTS = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.Series(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2000 + int(year), int(month), 1), end=datetime.date(2000 + int(year), int(month), 1) + pd.DateOffset(months=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=1), freq='D'))})
    #for each day of the year, create empty matrix to initialize with ride volumes
    MonthTS["matrix"] = [np.zeros((len(firms.index), len(brokers.index))) for x in range(len(MonthTS))]
    MonthTS['date'] = MonthTS['date'].dt.date
    MonthTS = MonthTS.set_index(['date'])

    #iterate over combonations of firm and brokerage, and append to matrix
    for idx1, firm in firms.iterrows():
        #MonthTS["matrix"] = MonthTS["matrix"].apply(lambda x : x.append([]))
        for idx2, broker in brokers.iterrows():
            #tallying taxi rides on the given day in either direction between firms and brokers
            tmp = currentMonth[(currentMonth["pu_block"] == str(firm.bctcb2010)) & (currentMonth["do_block"] == (broker.bctcb2010)) | ((currentMonth["do_block"] == str(firm.bctcb2010)) & (currentMonth["pu_block"] == str(broker.bctcb2010)))]
            tmp = tmp.groupby("pickup_datetime").count()
            MonthTS = pd.concat([MonthTS, tmp], axis = 1)
            #print(MonthTS.head(5))
            MonthTS["matrix"] = MonthTS.apply(lambda x: replaceVal(x, idx1, idx2), axis=1)
            MonthTS = MonthTS["matrix"]

    #at this point, for the index on a given day, matrix[i][j] represents the ride between firm i and brokerage j on the given day
    return MonthTS

secondary function called:
def replaceVal(x, idx1, idx2):
    if (x.pu_block == x.pu_block):
        (x.matrix)[idx1][idx2] = x.pu_block
    return x.matrix

Tried reproducing this error by doing runs with single combinations of rows from the two other sets, and could not do it. When I print out x.matrix at the point of failure it prints nan.
To Summarize, df looks like this before apply:
            matrix
date
2012-02-01 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-02 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-03 [[0, 1, 2, ...
...
2012-02-27 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-28 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-29 [[0, 1, 2, ...

And like this after:
            matrix
date
2012-02-01 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-02 [[0, 1, 2, ...
2012-02-03 nan
...
2012-02-27 nan
2012-02-28 nan
2012-02-29 nan


Do you mind providing a [mcve]?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Is there a reason in your secondary function for asking if x.pu_block is equal to itself (which should always be true)? Barring a minimal dataset to test with, I have a suspicion that you were wanting to test x.pu_block with x.do_block or something like that. Without a test set, it's hard to say what should or shouldn't be happening here.
